# Surface pro pen won't work after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface-pro, pen

My surface pen stopped working after I upgraded my surface pro from windows 8.1 to windows 10. Any ideas what I need to do to get it to work again? I know that it is not a battery issue as it was working right before I upgraded.

Comment: Does touchscreen work?

Comment: Yes it does, but not for the pen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using a Surface Pro 3, here is the link for the drivers:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38826
Once you download them and install them, restart the computer and the pen should work.
If that doesn't solve your problems, see if the pen works on other touchscreens or Surface Pro(s).

Note: these drivers are compatible with windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

The Surface Pro 3 pen will work with Windows 10 if you replace the used batteries for brand new ones.

Comment: It seems the drivers needed update

Comment: The new battery at nothing to do with the pen working with Windows 10.  It sounds like the pen just had bad battery.  If the pen had a battery that wasn't dead it would have worked.  You have connected two unrelated things together.